# javascript - open link as new window in vuejs2 template

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I need to open a new window with a certain height and width.

in vuejs2 I have something like this:

> ```
> <el-table-column label="Link" width="80">
>   <template scope="props">
>     <a v-bind:href="''+props.row.link+''" target="chart"> Link to chart </a>
>   </template>
> </el-table-column>
> ```
>
> and in props.row.link have: http://host/charts/index.php?par=sth
>   So this href open in new tab but without height and width and not in new window.

At html is so simple:

```
<a href="http://host/charts/index.php?par=1" onclick="window.open('http://host/charts/index.php?par=1', 'chart', 'width=1225, height=770'); return false;">Link to chart</a>
```

How to achieve this in vue js 2,
maybe as click method?

Comment: Try this: <a v-bind:href="''+props.row.link+''" target="_blank"> Link to chart </a>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

`<a v-bind:href="''+props.row.link+''" target="chart"> Link to chart </a>`

use

`<a href="" v-on:click.stop.prevent="openWindow(props.row.link)">Link to chart</a>`

This will prevent the link from being clicked and redirected. 
Additionally it calls the function "openWindow" that is declared in the methods-object of your component:

```
openWindow: function (link) {
  window.open(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! <a href="" v-on:click.stop.prevent="OpenWindow(''+props.row.link+'')">Link to chart</a> Works proper.

Answer (score 0):

don't use v-bind:href instead, call a function which will open new window

Comment: Ok. trying call function but how to pass the parameter from props.row.link...                                                                                  
   <a @click="OpenWindow('props.row.link')" >chart</a>       unfortunately get string not parameter from row.    My method: OpenWindow(link) {
      window.open('' + link + '', 'chart', 'width=1225, height=770')
      console.log(link) -->get string!
    }